# In which case can I use zip and combineLatest? RxSwift

Tags: rx-swift

I don't know in which case to use zip and in what case combineLatest.
Can someone help me?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

The `zip` operator is needed when you want to combine two Observables that have a common source and where you want to wait until all update from that source before it emits a value. The `combineLatest` operator is used for all other cases.

I suggest you use `combineLatest` as your default and use `zip` if you know for a fact that you need it.

If the observables being combined are both singles, then the two operators are the same. In fact, if you are using the `Single` type, `zip` is the only operator available.

The primary use of `zip` otherwise is when you are re-subscribing to an observable that another observable that is being combined depends on. Paste this into a properly configured playground:

```
import RxSwift
import Foundation

func exampleZip(a: Observable<Int>) -> Observable<(Int, String)> {
    let b = a.map { "\($0)" }
    return Observable.zip(a, b)
}

func exampleCombineLatest(a: Observable<Int>) -> Observable<(Int, String)> {
    let b = a.map { "\($0)" }
    return Observable.combineLatest(a, b)
}

exampleZip(a: Observable.from([1, 2, 3]))
    .subscribe(onNext: { print("zip", $0) })

exampleCombineLatest(a: Observable.from([1, 2, 3]))
    .subscribe(onNext: { print("combineLatest", $0) })
```

Here is the output you will get:

```
zip (1, "1")
zip (2, "2")
zip (3, "3")
combineLatest (1, "1")
combineLatest (2, "1")
combineLatest (2, "2")
combineLatest (3, "2")
combineLatest (3, "3")
```

See the difference?

Comment: thank you very much but I want to know how it is used in the real-life example

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. The above is real code and shows how to use `zip`.

Comment: Sorry for my bad English.
I mean zip is used for merging 2 RestAPIs with the purpose of waiting for both APIs to complete, then merging; combineLatest is suitable for checking true and false, for example, when the user enters enough characters in the user and password textfield, the login button will be enabled.
Thank you for your reply ^^

Comment: That is incorrect. When you are waiting for two APIs to complete, you could use either; both operators work the same. I have updated my answer.

Comment: thank you very much, i had found that info many time ^^

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53344514/16924255, you helped me again, thank you very much, rxswift is really hard for me to learn ^^